# How to choose the correct architecture for my PHP classes?

Tags: php, architecture

This is the first web app that i am building by myself.

Before coding i like to organize my ideas, do class and requiriments diagrams.

So i have to do this in my software

> -Add users.
>   -Add buy orders.

I am thinking my classes in two different ways.

Like this:

```
class User{
    function add()
    function edit()
}

class BuyOrder{
    function add()
    function edit()
}
```

Or

```
class Add{
   function user()
   function buyOrder()
}

class Edit{
    function user()
    function buyOrder()
}
```

As you can see they will do the same but with different writting.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: This not a design pattern. It's a architectural issue.

Comment: Both your approaches are wrong. A `User` should not now about adding or editing itself. The `Add` and `Edit` classes are just plain weird, but I understand you tried the reverse of your first approach. In your second case imagine you have many things to *add*. Your class would quickly grow out of control. Always keep the single responsibility principle in mind when writing classes. You may end up with a lot of classes, but at least they are manageable.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class User 
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   pubic string LastName { get; set; }
   public byte Age { get; set; }
   public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order 
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public decimal Price { get; set; }
   public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
}

public class Service 
{
   public User Create(User user) { };
   public User Read(Guid id) { };
   public void Update(User user) { };
   public void Delete(Guid id) { };

   public Order Create(Order order) { };
   public Order Read(Guid id) { };
   public void Update(Order order) { };
   public void Delete(Guid id) { };


   // Add orders to user basket
   public void AddOrdersToUserBasket(List<Order> orders, User user) { }; 
   public void AddOrdersToUserBasket(List<Order> orders, Guid id) { };

   // Get all orders of current user
   public List<Order> ReadOrdersForUser (Guid id) { };

   // Send orders and user data to process a delivery.
   public void Send ProcessOrdersAndUserData(List<Order> orders, User user) { };
}
```

Instead of void as return value, you can use the some wrapper:

```
public class Answer 
{
   public bool Result { get; set; }
   public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

And need to divide the service to UserSevice, OrderService and ProcessService.

Comment: Why not refactor the `Service` into their respective services right away?

Answer (score 0):

I think User and BuyOrder should be a class.

However, it doesn't make sense to me to have an add function be a part of these classes since the creation of a new instance of these classes effectively is the add.

Instead I would create AddUser and AddOrder functions which create the instances and properly add them where they need to be.